# How to load events and resources dynamically in fullcalendar for a selected date using angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to load the events and resources data from local json file for a selected date.

On clicking on date am getting my local json data through service call and pushed those data to events array as well as resources array.

But am not able to see the events and resources on the calendar.

Here am passing dayViewOption object to the calendar component.

```
dayViewOptions = {
      resourceAreaWidth:'334px',
      refetchResourcesOnNavigate:true,
      now: '2017-12-25',
      refetchEvents:true,
      editable: true,
      height: 580,
      header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
      },
      slotLabelFormat:['H'],
      defaultView: 'timelineDay',
      slotWidth:15,
      resourceColumns: [
        {
            labelText: '',
            field: 'title'
        }
      ],
      resources: [

      ],
      events: [

      ]
  }
```

this is my calendar component developed in angular.

```
<camp-day-view-calendar [options]="dayViewOptions"></camp-day-view-calendar>
```

whenever date is selected, am calling following gotToDay function for formatting the data, pushing the data and navigating to selected date.

```
goToDay(dayData){
    let year = dayData.getFullYear();
    let month = dayData.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? `0${dayData.getMonth()+1}` : dayData.getMonth()+1;
    let day = dayData.getDate() < 10 ? `0${dayData.getDate()}` : dayData.getDate();
    let currentDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;    
    this.calendarService.getCalendarDetails(currentDate)
      .subscribe(
        success => {
          this.response = success;
          this.formatDayViewOptions(success);          
            $('camp-day-view-calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',currentDate);
        },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }



  formatDayViewOptions(res){
    this.dayViewOptions.resources = [];
    this.dayViewOptions.events = [];
    let calnderDetails = res.data;
    let dataLength = res.data.length;    
    for(let i = 0; i < dataLength ; i++){
      let dayColor = this.dayViewColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
      let deploymentObj = calnderDetails[i].deployment;
      let resourceObj = {"id": deploymentObj.id, "title": deploymentObj.name,"channelName":deploymentObj.channel, "eventColor": dayColor };
      this.dayViewOptions.resources.push(resourceObj);

      let resouceEventObj = { "id": deploymentObj.id, "resourceId": deploymentObj.id, "start": deploymentObj.calendar.startDate, "end": deploymentObj.calendar.endDate }
      this.dayViewOptions.events.push(resouceEventObj);
    }    
    $('camp-day-view-calendar').fullCalendar("updateEvents",this.dayViewOptions.events);
  }
```

Here is the sample local json data

```
{
    "data":[
        {
        "deployment": {
          "id": "a",
          "name": "Ev1234567890123...Ev12345678903_1",          
          "calendar": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "string",
            "startDate": "2017-12-06",
            "endDate": "2017-12-08"
          },          
          "channel": "SMS"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Anybody, please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

events and resources as functions should help in this. these functions will be called when on calling fullCalendar('refetchEvents') and fullCalendar('refetchResources'). Call this refetchEvents and resources on receiving the data from the api call you have.